# How to monitor RAM ECC errors on i7-3612QE processor in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, hardware, intel, rasdaemon

I would like to monitor the health of the DRAM on an industrial single-board computer with the following memory controller:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep DRAM
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
```

Running Debian 10 I tried

```
$ modprobe ie31200_edac
$ ras-mc-ctl --status
ras-mc-ctl: drivers are loaded.
$ ras-mc-ctl --layout
ras-mc-ctl: Error: No memories found at via edac.
$ ls /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/
power  subsystem  uevent
```

I'm expecting useful output for the memory layout and an `mc0` sub-directory (this works fine on a 4th Gen single-board computer from the same vendor). Am I loading the right kernel module?

---

Details about the memory:

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type=memory
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 5, 20 bytes
Memory Controller Information
        Error Detecting Method: 64-bit ECC
        Error Correcting Capabilities:
                Single-bit Error Correcting
        Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave
        Current Interleave: One-way Interleave
        Maximum Memory Module Size: 8192 MB
        Maximum Total Memory Size: 16384 MB
        Supported Speeds:
                Other
        Supported Memory Types:
                Other
        Memory Module Voltage: Unknown
        Associated Memory Slots: 2
                0x0006
                0x0007
        Enabled Error Correcting Capabilities:
                Single-bit Error Correcting

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM0
        Bank Connections: None
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: DIMM
        Installed Size: 4096 MB (Single-bank Connection)
        Enabled Size: 4096 MB (Single-bank Connection)
        Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM1
        Bank Connections: None
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: DIMM
        Installed Size: 4096 MB (Single-bank Connection)
        Enabled Size: 4096 MB (Single-bank Connection)
        Error Status: OK

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
        Error Information Handle: 0x002F
        Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x002A
        Error Information Handle: 0x002D
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: 4096 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM0
        Bank Locator: BANK 0
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: None
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Not Specified
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        Asset Tag: Unknown
        Part Number: Not Specified
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x002A
        Error Information Handle: 0x002E
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: 4096 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM1
        Bank Locator: BANK 2
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: None
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Not Specified
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        Asset Tag: Unknown
        Part Number: Not Specified
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s
```